# Trouble scaling basic Image in Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, image-scaling, modifier

My problem is very simple. Yet I have been struggling for hours. Please end my insanity.

I have a row with a box in the middle. I want to put an image in the box and make it so the image touches the top and bottom of the box (Scales/fills vertically). I would also be okay with it filling the whole thing (even if the aspect ratio gets messed up). [I want the actual blue image to stretch and fill to the top and bottom of the white box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9yIA.png)

Here is my code:

```
@Preview(device = "spec:width=1280dp,height=800dp,dpi=310")
@Composable
fun Preview(){
    Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically, horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(.5f).background(Color.Red)) {
                BadgeImage()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun BadgeImage() {
    Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.badge_blank),
        contentDescription = null,
        modifier = Modifier.background(Color.White),
        contentScale = ContentScale.FillHeight,
        )
}
```

I have tried countless modifiers on the Badge image composable. I have tried every contentScale.

I can't even get fill bounds to work. Please save me from my misery <3.

P.S. My image size is 2000 by 1200. Larger than my box I am trying to put it in.

Update:  [Here is my image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3stq.png)

Comment: Will actively work with posted solutions to quickly get and upvote and accepted answer.

Comment: Hi, can you share a link of the image resource, so I can try to reproduce the exact output?

Comment: @stoyan_vuchev  I have updated my post to contain the image resource

Comment: What is weird to me is the image Composable is actually scaling to fill. As the entire parent area is filled with the image composable's white background. But the image itself is still small within the white background. Why isn't the image scaling to take up the white area?

Comment: I just confirmed this is still an issue by testing this exact code and image above on a separate computer with a fresh android studio code install. The image is imported in androdi studio via resource manager > Import drawables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not in the code, but rather in the image itself. It has a transparent area around the actual image you're trying to adjust the bounds to. I recommend to import and use the image without the transparent area.

I've managed to remove the transparent area of the image. [Here is a link of the cropped image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUK0J.jpg).

Comment: Checking this solution now. Will update in a few thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Can't believe I didn't see that.

Comment: You're welcome! Don't worry, such things happen to all of us from time to time. 